# A question on a specific partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $f(x,y,z,w)$ be a real function with continuous partial derivatives, satisfying the following partial differential equation
$$
2\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)
=f\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial x}\right)
$$

What is the solution of that equation?

Edit: We can assume that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial x}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}$

**My attempt:** I noticed that
$$
(\ast)\quad \frac{\partial(1/f)}{\partial x}=-\frac{1}{f^2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
$$
so
$$
\frac{\partial^2(1/f)}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{2}{f^3}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)-\frac{1}{f^2}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}=
\frac{1}{f^3}\left[2\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)-f\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}\right]
$$
Therefore, $(\ast)$ is satisfied iff
$$
\frac{\partial^2(1/f)}{\partial x\partial y}=0
$$
What next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next, integrate in $x$ and then in $y$ to get $1/f = g(y,z,w)+h(x,z,w)$ for some functions $g,h$.

Comment: Thanks. I was not sure if I can integrate.  Is the continuous partial derivatives allow us to integrate?

Comment: Yes, but if you don’t like the idea of integrating, just think that the equation is saying that the Hessian of $1/f$ is diagonal, hence once you derive w.r.t. $x$ you must end up with a function which does not depends on $y$ and vice versa. Then the dependence on those two variables must be “split” in two separate functions.

Comment: By the way, $g$ and $h$ can not be any two function, right? For instance, if $f(x,y,z,w)=\frac{z}{x}+\frac{w}{y}$.